# Network usage monitor for linux for specific hours?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-monitoring

I need a network usage monitor for linux like vnStat that have the ability to turn off metering at specific hours.

I have a broadband connection with limited and unlimited bandwidth respect to time. I have unlimited internet during 2.00am to 8.00am and limited internet of 2.5GB per month during other times.
So if I use vnStat, i cannot count the actual usage of my 2.5GB (which is from 0800 to 0200). While I was in windows, I used networx which did the job perfectly. I cannot find an alternatives in linux. I used that in linux using wine, it works fine but I need to install wine for this single 2mb executable.

I like to know about alternatives in linux or some trick like startup-shell-script to make vnStat or any other work only at my hours.

I am using ubuntu 13.04 (gnome-shell) .

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Networx on Windows, and am also looking for similar solution for Ubuntu.

The best I have found so far is **BitMeter OS**: http://codebox.org.uk/pages/bitmeterOs

Comment: this one also doesnt have the ability to turn off monitoring at specified interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vnstat_switcher.sh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435486/is-it-possible-to-set-on-peak-and-off-peak-hours-in-vnstat-for-monitoring-bandwi/444036#444036) answered by me on the question on askubuntu [Is it possible to set on-peak and off-peak hours in vnstat for monitoring bandwidth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435486/is-it-possible-to-set-on-peak-and-off-peak-hours-in-vnstat-for-monitoring-bandwi). It uses 2 databases for normal and night (2-8 AM) usage.